# Unable to fetch value from dynamo db operation using async/await in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

Recently AWS upgraded lambda run time environment to Node js 8.10. I have created a lambda function which uses async/await operation.The way it works is when an entry is being made to dynamodb table, a message is sent to sns topic with primary key of table as part of message which triggers another lambda function. When executing second lambda function and querying dynamodb table with primary key , i am unable to fetch value from await. When printing value in console log , it returns undefined. I don't need to pass any value in return key so i am not using that to pass any value. Below is the code snippet.

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    let tableName = "vedablogs";
    let idvalue = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    let id = idvalue.toString();

    let params = {
                TableName: tableName,
                KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :idvalue",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#id": "id"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":idvalue": id
                }
            };

     let queryParams = await docClient.query(params).promise();
     console.log('queryParams'+queryParams.Item);
     return;

};
```

Comment: Is this your code as you're testing it? `queryParams.Item` will hold the returned item from your `query`. Can you clarify what you're unable to fetch?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace that returns undefined when you use queryParams.Item

Comment: .Item will be undefined if that item does not exist- what does `console.log(JSON.stringify(queryParams))` return?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace that returns error > converting circular structure to json plus i ran a query on dynamodb table with key which i received in sns message, it shows a row entry for that key.

Comment: Hmm- something's definitely up if you can't stringify the response- the alternative is to add `let util = require('util')` to the top, and instead use `console.log(util.inspect(new Error(), { depth: 10 }))`

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace it was slight typo mistake. we have to use queryParams.Items  instead of queryParams.Item. Phew, it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Any one facing this issue, solution is to use Items instead of item. You can console log values as follow.

```
 console.log("query params is>"+queryParams.Items);
  queryParams.Items.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('items is'+JSON.stringify(item));
    });
```